# React Router passing props to a previously defined element

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a question regarding React and React Router.

Say I have an application that is organized like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
    <Header/>
    <Route path= "/" />
    <Route path="/login" />
    <Route path= "/anotherPage" />
    )
  }
}
```

(This is not the fully functional code, I have simplified it.) Assume Header contains something that I want as a header, and thus want to show up on every page path.

Now say I want to change the header depending on a variable inside "/login", say it is a boolean variable called "loggedIn". When the login button is pressed inside "/login", the loggedIn variable becomes true. I want to pass this to the Header now.

I set up a callback function:

```
 myCallbackLogin = dataFromChildLogin => {
   this.state.user = dataFromChildLogin;
 }
```

and I can confirm it works, so there is now a variable inside the App class where "this.state.user" = true. Assume this to be true for the next code. Note that this is being done after information from the "/login" page is manipulated. How do I pass this to the Header file? I assumed it would be done like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
    <Header loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn} />
    <Route path= "/" />
    <Route path="/login" />
    <Route path= "/anotherPage" />
    )
  }
}
```

so now that in the Header.js file, I can access that variable as "this.props.loggedIn". But for some reason it doesn't receive it? Is this because the Header is only rendered once, and thus doesn't pass any new props after it is rendered the first time? If so, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React you **never** mutate state directly. Instead you use `this.setState({ /* ... */ })`.

`this.setState` tells React that state has been updated and therefore can trigger a new render-cycle with the new data provided.

If you want you can learn more about [Component State in the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do).

In your case:

```
myCallbackLogin = dataFromChildLogin => {
  this.setState({ user: dataFromChildLogin });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. It's because you are setting the state incorrectly( [read more about setState](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781)). Provided

```
myCallbackLogin = dataFromChildLogin => {
   this.state.user = dataFromChildLogin;
 }
```

is in same file as your App component.

replace

```
this.state.user = dataFromChildLogin;
```

with

```
this.setState({user: dataFromChildLogin});
```